# KDE 5 of Debian Jessie - What Qt version was used to compile it?

Tags: debian, repository, dependencies, qt, kde5

I had go back to Windows a while ago because of the incompatibility of linux desktops with high-res (UHD) and touch screens. As now it got much better than before, I'd like to come back to linux, as Windows is really driving me crazy.

However, while I know that Gnome supports touch and high-res very well, I'd like to know whether it's supported too in KDE. Now since KDE is compiled with Qt, I know that Qt has provided a fix for high-res with an environment variable `qt_device_pixel_ratio`, and I can imagine that setting that will rescale everything in KDE properly, as it worked with everything else.

This fix only works with Qt version >= 5.4. So before I continue, I need to know what version of Qt was used to compile the KDE 5 package in Debian Jessie. How can I know that?

Note: I would like to avoid manual DPI scaling of fonts and windows as it's not as nice.

This will be good also for me to learn how to follow dependencies on the debian website, as I didn't fully understand how to do that on the Debian repos website.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt 5 is built by the [`qtbase-opensource-src`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/qtbase-opensource-src) source package in Debian. Looking at the linked tracker page shows that the version in Jessie (`stable`) is [5.3.2+dfsg-4-deb8u1](https://packages.debian.org/source/stable/qtbase-opensource-src), so basically 5.3.2, which is older than 5.4...

5.4 is available in Stretch (the next version of Debian, currently in development), and 5.5 is in `experimental` (a sort of staging area for packages which need testing but aren't considered usable for a stable version of the distribution yet).

Finding this out by going through the dependencies (starting from [`meta-kde`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/meta-kde), the highest-level KDE package) is rather difficult since most of KDE in Debian still builds with Qt 4. I actually looked for the Qt 5 libraries in `aptitude` and worked my way up from there.